# Javascript code for change css width of a class not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The simple code for change width of a class in css code using javascript is not working. I have given the width is `200px`. Then i want to change the width to `50px`. i want to use a javascript code to change width. But it is not working.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("main").style.width = "50px";
```

```css
.main {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/33zc0efq/

Answer (score 2):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of object so you need to specify index for that. Change it to `document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].style.width="50px";`

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].style.width="50px";
```

```css
.main{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
</div>
```